# neo4j cypher: Filter on node property based variable substring

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

I need to create between two nodes where the first node has some String property (named `keyword` for example) and the second node has property (named 'text') the 'text' property contains the value of `keyword` within
some thing like:

```
start node1=node(0),node2=node(1) 
match node1-[r:RELATED_TO]->node2 
where node1.prop1.substring(node2.prop2) create unique r 
return r
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need a CONTAINS or node1.prop1.indexOf(node2.prop2) function which is not there yet. Could you please raise an issue in neo4j, https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues, or provide a pull request and implement it?